# VS 2010 Setup Project - Installer when upgrading doesn't update the .exe or .config files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer, setup-project

I have a problem with an application installer compiled in VS2010.

Version 1.1 installs fine, I get the .exe, .config and referenced assemblies.

I uninstall, then install 1.2.  Again everything works as expected.

Uninstall, the install 1.1 again.

Next I install 1.2, the installer updates the referenced assmeblies (I can see the modified date is different) but not the .exe or the .config.

Is there something I'm missing config wise in the setup project?

Thanks

Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to read:

[Default File Versioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368267%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Note: it's not the AssemblyVersion attribute that is important rather the AssemblyFileVersion attribute.  The former is used by the GAC and Strong Name contracts while the later maps to the Windows Native FileVersion structure.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually answered my own question.

The problem was that I'd not incremented the assembly version of one of the referenced .dlls.  Although the timestamp was being updated, the existing files were not being overwritten or patched.

I used

`msiexec.exe /i "\\path\myApp.msi" /l*vx! C:\temp\install.log`

to log what was happening and found the problem in there.

Since then I've incremented the offending assembly's version number and all is ok.